# Get attribute from dynamo db table

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

im new to pyton and lambda scripting. Im trying to get a value from "extension" attribute from a dynamodb table with a primary partition key only.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
import json
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print(event)
    extension=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('AgentExtension',"Not Available")
    table = dynamodb.Table('mm-vm-solution-VoicemailStack-1BCDEMP76ZZA6-UsersTable-YYZ15DDH1LHR')
    try:
      response = table.query(
        IndexName= 'AgentExtensionIndex',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('extension').eq(extension)
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        return {
                "Success":"False",
                "Reason":e.response['Error']['Message']
               }
    else:
        #item = response['Items']
        print("GetItem succeeded:")
        print(json.dumps(response))
        if "Item" in response:
            return {
                "Success":"True"
            }
        else:
            return {
                "Success":"False",
                "Reason":"No Records Found"
            }
```

Dynamo db table is composed of a primary partition key "agentId (String)". GSI is enabled as you can see in the below screenshot.

[Dynamo db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trL7T.png)

**** update ****
I made it possible to retrieve the "Success":"True" with this last part:

```
 else:
        #item = response['Item']
        print("GetItem succeeded:")
        print(json.dumps(response))
        print(response['Items'])
        if "Items" in response:
            return{
                "Success":"True",
                "Extension":response["Items"][{extension}]
                }
```

It is printing me this:

```
    {
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      30,
      "lambda_handler",
      "\"Extension\":response[\"Items\"][{extension}]"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers, not set"
}
```

I just need this output:

```
"Success":"True"
"Extension:"7777"
```

Please help me achieve this and i will mark the answer as correct!

Comment: You identify an item by its unique key (simple pk or composite pk+sk). To get that item, you call get_item and it returns all attributes, by default. What is not working for you?

Comment: Lambda si working but is showing no results. The value is in the table (7777) under the extension attribute. So i don't understand why doesn't work.

Comment: There has to be something im missing.

Comment: I've tried to modify the index with All/include/keys only but no luck. Still returning no results.

Comment: When you say "no results", do you mean it does not find your item, or that it does find the item but does not return the attributes you want?

Comment: It is not finding the item. If you take a look that the lambda, you'll see that im using an event were i extract the "AgentExtension", on the test event: "AgentExtension": "7777". So from what i understand it should compare that value to the keyconditionexpression "extension". The table contains a "7777" value under the extension attribute. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: I'll post 3 screenshots at the end of the post. One for the lambda code, other for the test event and other for the dynamo db table so you can better understand what i am at.

Comment: Never post images of code. Add code, properly formatted, to your question.

Comment: I'd be tempted to validate your assumptions here by using the awscli or the AWS console to issue the same query against that index. Confirm that it works there first. Your code looks reasonable to me.

Comment: jarmod sorry for the formating issues. I've updated the post with new screenshots and the current lambda code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to DynamoDB [DocumentClient query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query) does not contain a single item. It contains a list of items.

You are testing:

```
if 'Item' in response:
```

You should be testing:

```
if 'Items' in response:
```

Note that multiple items could match the query, so be prepared to handle multiple items in the response. If you simply want to retrieve an attribute value, e.g. `extension`, from the first result then you can do this as follows:

```
response["Items"][0]['extension']
```

Comment: Code updated to 'Items' in response, same results!

Comment: Print the value of `extension` being submitted to your query. Make sure it's correct. Then use the awscli or AWS console to issue the same query against the same table. What happens?

Comment: I've added what you suggested at the end of the post for more clarity. Thanks jarmod.

Comment: OK, great. So you have successfully retrieved the item and it's in the form of a Python dict. Your latest code tries to get the key '7777' from the dict but, of course, that's not a key (it's a value) so it results in KeyError. At this point, your code is working (you have successfully queried the item). You should accept this answer, if it resolved your issue. Any subsequent problems related to retrieving items from a dict can be a follow-up question (though I think you have what you need at this point).

Comment: jarmod. It is working but i need to print ONLY the extension value. Please look at the end of the post one more time if its not too much to ask. I don't need all attributes. Im only needing the extension. Please correct me.

Comment: You already know the extension. It's in `extension`. You used it to query the items. If you really want to retrieve it from the first returned item, that's available in `response["Items"][0]['extension']`

Answer (score 1):

To get only certain attributes from Dynamo, we need to use `ProjectionExpression`, and map the attributes with in expression in `ExpressionAttributeNames`

Might look something like this.

```
table = dynamodb.Table('test-table')
response = table.get_item(
        Key={'agentId': "agent1"},
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#name': 'name'
        },
        ProjectionExpression= '#name'
)
```

Update: To Query only by an attribute without primary key, we need to create a GSI and query with that index.
In this case partitionKey is `name` and index name is `by-name-index`

[image]

and use `query` to fetch data by GSI

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('test-table')
response = table.query(
        IndexName= 'by-name-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('name').eq("john")
)
print(response['Items'])
```

Comment: I need to get only the "name" attribute of that table. So im just looking for a name under that column. I don't know what to do with "agentId" in this case. It is possible to only look after an attribute without taking into consideration the Primary key?

Comment: oh! you want to query the table only by `name` ,without the primary key? we need to create `GSI`(Global secondary Index) on attribute name. Let me add some details.

Comment: Oh that would be of great help, thanks in advance Balu. To bring a little bit of clarity: 

Im comparing an event attribute  to the primary key values of the table in case there is a match. 

    #print(event)
    extension=event['Details']['ContactData']['Attributes'].get('AgentExtension',"Not Available")
    table = dynamodb.Table('AgentsExtensions')
    try:
        response = table.get_item(
                Key={
                    'uuid': extension
                    }
                )

I need to compare "extension" to the "name" attribute of the table.

Comment: i updated the answer, not sure if this is what you are looking for. I am bit confused a bit with previous comment :)  Can you update question with few more details if this is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes i saw the update. I've updated the post with more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated the post once again, sorry. Now should make more sense.

Comment: Updated code from screen shot looks great @GabrielGuiridlian. it should work , as long as GSI is created and value exists in table. Are you getting an error or just doesn't return any records?

Comment: Result: 

{
  "Reason": "No Records Found",
  "Success": "False"
}

test event is set to       "AgentExtension" : "7777"

Value "7777" is under "extension database attribute, i don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Im updating the post with a screenshot of the db for your validation. Thanks!